# Boosting FM range transmission from Raspberry Pi

Tags: gpio, power, radio

I want to boost FM transmission range when using Raspberry Pi as transmitter.
I found this circle:[image]
Source: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ipod-and-itunes/0596007787/ch01s07.html

Will it boost my FM range?
Can I connect it safely to raspberry pi? (gpio ground pin as input antenna)
If not what need to be changed?
I don't want to break my Raspberry Pi.
Link saying power source should be 12v 500mA.

Comment: It's hard to tell since half the components are not labeled wrt their spec or make&model. Do note that tampering with RF circuits and/or operating an unlicenced transmitter may be forbidden/unlawful in many countries (might depend on where you're located). Beside that: I have the feeling that this question (if you drop the reference to the Pi) might be suited much better at electronics.

Comment: If you dont blow up atleast one Raspberry Pi then you are doing it wrong :D OK- Seriously though. Maybe you should first learn how to protect your "hardware" before hacking it. example, using diodes and how transistors work. You are jumping into the ocean but can't even swim across a puddle of water.... You are destined to blow something up.

Answer (score 1):

Boosting transmission from a digital output without a low-pass filter or band-pass filter is usually a very bad idea, as the harmonics of a digital waveform can interfere in lots of different radio frequency bands.

Answer (score -2):

The Raspberry PI has 3v or 5v outputs so you're going to need another 12v power supply.  It looks like you just connect your current antenna from the PI to the base of the transistor.

Answer (score -2):

The transistor limits the voltage to 0.7 volt (pin B) while raspberry gpio tries to give 3.3. This can destroy your Pi